# android studio 3.1.2 debug app, "attach debugger to android process" can't find the process when app running in phone

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

see the picture, the app is running in phone.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsOpG.png)
then in the phone, I find the developer options->debugging->Select debug app->no debug application set.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXJAV.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heBPo.jpg)

Hi, everybody. I want to debug a app in my phone, First, I run the app in my phone. Then, I connect the phone in my laptop use cable. but can't find the app process in as.
Then, I use my colleague phone, In his phone, the app I want to debug in the "debug application set" list, then I can debug the app in as.
I want to know, How to add the app process to the "debug application set".
Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run debug version of app. Just go to Build Variants panel and select debug varian. Release varian also can be debugged. In this case you have to specify in your `build.gradle` in `buildTypes -> release` section `debuggable true` property and in `AndroidManifest.xml` in application tag add properties `android:debuggable="true" tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode"`. Don't forget to roll this change back before production.

Comment: thank you, guy. I know the real reason. I have the jar source code, I need an app to debug the jar source code. The app produce from an 3th company.

Comment: The company give me the app is Release version. This is the real reaon. Later, I report the promblem to the company, Then, They send me an Debug version. Then my jar source code can attach to the app. Thank you very much.